# What is the Build Drop Location environment variable name for PowerShell in TFS 2015/2017

Tags: powershell, environment-variables, build-agent

In previous versions of TFS (before 2015), there was a build environment variable for PowerShell called: TF_BUILD_DROPLOCATION, which gave the The location of the drop:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh850448%28v=vs.120%29.aspx.

I can't find the equivalent variable in TFS 2017. 
What is the best practice to get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Build agent tasks taking over things are different.  What I do to see the various build environment variables is to make a simple batch file containing this:

```
SET C:\temp\EnvVars.txt
```

That'll produce a quick list of what is available.

Here's what I see with the TFS 2017 build agent:

```
agent.jobstatus=Succeeded 
AGENT_BUILDDIRECTORY=C:\Agent\_work\2
AGENT_HOMEDIRECTORY=C:\Agent 
AGENT_ID=2 AGENT_JOBNAME=Build
AGENT_JOBSTATUS=Succeeded
AGENT_MACHINENAME=BUILDMACHINE
AGENT_NAME=BUILDMACHINE
AGENT_OS=Windows_NT
AGENT_ROOTDIRECTORY=C:\Agent\_work
AGENT_SERVEROMDIRECTORY=C:\Agent\externals\vstsom
AGENT_TEMPDIRECTORY=C:\Agent\_work\_temp
AGENT_TOOLSDIRECTORY=C:\Agent\_work\_tool
AGENT_VERSION=2.122.1
AGENT_WORKFOLDER=C:\Agent\_work
BUILD_ARTIFACTSTAGINGDIRECTORY=C:\Agent\_work\2\a
BUILD_BINARIESDIRECTORY=C:\Agent\_work\2\b
BUILD_BUILDID=2036
BUILD_BUILDNUMBER=Database Build_20190708.2
BUILD_BUILDURI=vstfs:///Build/Build/2036
BUILD_CONTAINERID=2281
BUILD_DEFINITIONNAME=Database Build
BUILD_DEFINITIONVERSION=17
BUILD_QUEUEDBY=Smith, John
BUILD_QUEUEDBYID=8c588342-b87a-40cb-9b8c-a0ed10b57a3f
BUILD_REASON=Manual
BUILD_REPOSITORY_CLEAN=false
BUILD_REPOSITORY_GIT_SUBMODULECHECKOUT=False
BUILD_REPOSITORY_ID=$/
BUILD_REPOSITORY_LOCALPATH=C:\Agent\_work\2\s
BUILD_REPOSITORY_NAME=Collection
BUILD_REPOSITORY_PROVIDER=TfsVersionControl
BUILD_REPOSITORY_TFVC_WORKSPACE=ws_2_2
BUILD_REPOSITORY_URI=http://TFSSERVER:8080/tfs/Project/
BUILD_REQUESTEDFOR=Smith, John
BUILD_REQUESTEDFOREMAIL=John.Smith@Mailinator.com
BUILD_REQUESTEDFORID=7a588222-b66a-40ee-9b2a-a0ba10b12a3f
BUILD_SOURCEBRANCH=$/Collection/Project/Code
BUILD_SOURCEBRANCHNAME=Code
BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY=C:\Agent\_work\2\s
BUILD_SOURCEVERSION=9811
BUILD_SOURCEVERSIONAUTHOR=Smith, John
BUILD_SOURCEVERSIONMESSAGE=Added missing permission
BUILD_STAGINGDIRECTORY=C:\Agent\_work\2\a
```

Answer (score 1):

You can list all Environment Variables with the following command:

```
get-childitem ENV:\
```

I am assuming you could create a simple build job that executes this and then look at the console output to determine what the name is of the Environment Variable you need.